# How to fill area under curve in seaborn distribution plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have two variables

```
x = [1.883830, 7.692308,8.791209, 9.262166]
y = [5.337520, 4.866562, 2.825746, 6.122449]
```

And I want to fit a Gaussian distribution using the seaborn wrapped for matplotlib. It seems like the `sns.distplot` function is the best way to do this, but I can't figure out how to fill in the area under the curve. Help?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
sns.distplot(x,kde_kws={"shade":True}, kde=False, fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, color="red", label="2016", fit_kws={'color':'red'});
sns.distplot(y,kde_kws={"shade":True}, kde=False, fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, color="blue", label="2017", fit_kws={'color':'blue'})
```

I think the "shade" argument could be part of the `fit_kws` argument but I haven't gotten this to work.

Another option would be to use `ax.fill()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the `shade` argument is not supported for `fit_kws` unlike for the `kde_kws`. But as you guessed, we can fill the area under the two curves using `ax.fill_between()`. We will have to get the lines from the `ax` object and their x-y data and then use that to fill the area under the curves. Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1.883830, 7.692308,8.791209, 9.262166]
y = [5.337520, 4.866562, 2.825746, 6.122449]
ax = sns.distplot(x, fit_kws={"color":"red"}, kde=False,
        fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, label="label 1");
ax = sns.distplot(y, fit_kws={"color":"blue"}, kde=False,
        fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, label="label 2");

# Get the two lines from the axes to generate shading
l1 = ax.lines[0]
l2 = ax.lines[1]

# Get the xy data from the lines so that we can shade
x1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,0]
y1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,1]
x2 = l2.get_xydata()[:,0]
y2 = l2.get_xydata()[:,1]
ax.fill_between(x1,y1, color="red", alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(x2,y2, color="blue", alpha=0.3)

plt.show(block=False)
```

The result is shown below:
[image]

Comment: @AmitSingh Is it possible to output/print the AUC values?

Comment: @kkhatri99 since we have the `x` and `y` data of the lines, we can calculate the values of area under the curves but PyPlot does not provide any built-in routine to do that, as far as I know.

Comment: @AmitSingh Thanks for the response. I was able to get the areas using the np.trapz function          https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html